# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression" when trying to delete row from database

Tags: c#, oledb

```
    OleDbCommand system = new OleDbCommand();
    system.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    system.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE(ID= '" + 
                          txtStudentIDnumber.Text + "')";
    system.Connection = mydatabase;

    mydatabase.Open();
    system.ExecuteNonQuery();
    dataGridView1.Update();

    this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(csharrpfinalprojectDataSet);
    mydatabase.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Student Record Deleted.", "deleting record...");
```

Comment: I hope that you are very sure that `txtStudentIDnumber.Text` is really just that number. (search for sql injection)

Comment: What happen if, in your txtStudentIDNumber, someone writes: "1 OR ID > 0" ? Please read about SQL Injection

Answer (score 2):

In your command text you need to remove single quotes `(')` around the `txtStudentIDnumber.Text` as it appears ID is of type integer and you are passing it as string. Following should fix the error.

```
system.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE(ID= " + txtStudentIDnumber.Text + ")";
```

EDIT: With respect to @mdb comments, you should always use [Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) in your query so that you can avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Consider the following:

```
OleDbCommand system = new OleDbCommand();
system.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
system.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE ID = ?";
OleDbParameter parameter = new OleDbParameter("ID", txtStudentIDnumber.Text);
system.Parameters.Add(parameter);
system.Connection = mydatabase;

mydatabase.Open();
system.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataGridView1.Update();
```

Comment: While you may be correct about the quoting issue, this is not a very good solution, as this code is still wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: @mdb, absolutely right, Forgot to add that to my answer. and when I came back, saw that in the comments to the question and left it as it is

Comment: Thanks sir..but my only problem is how long will my database to update..it takes 5mins or more..i dont know if its working or not?

Comment: the oledbparameters are working..thanks sir you save my work!! how can i vote to your answer?

Comment: @ansie23, I see you joined today, you may accept the answer if you think its correct. See [How does accepting an answer works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and Welcome to Stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

```
OleDbCommand system = new OleDbCommand();
system.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
system.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Student WHERE ID=@ID";
system.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtStudentIDnumber.Text);
system.Connection = mydatabase;

mydatabase.Open();
system.ExecuteNonQuery();
dataGridView1.Update();

this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(csharrpfinalprojectDataSet);
mydatabase.Close();

MessageBox.Show("Student Record Deleted.", "deleting record...");
```

Answer (score 1):

What will happen when user input for `txtStudentIDNumber` is,

```
1 or 1=1
```

In that case hardcoded SQL string will be,

```
DELETE FROM Student WHERE(ID=1 or 1=1)
```

So prefer *parameterized* sql statement instead of hard-coded string.

```
using(OleDbConnection cn=new OleDbConnection(cnStr))
 {
  using(OleDbCommand cmd=new OleDbCommand())
   {
    cmd.CommandText="DELETE FROM Student WHERE ID=@ID";
    cmd.Connection=cn;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID",SqlDbType.Int).Value=txtStudentIDnumber.Text;
    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
   }
 }
```